# 'Shape - append' queries equivalence nowdays

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I have been converting a program written in VB to C# in the last few weeks.
In some places I noticed queries written in a weird way, the words 'Shape' and 'Append' appeared.
For instance:

```
SHAPE {SELECT Test, IdQuestion, QuestionName, QuestionTimeLimit, ImageLocation 
FROM dbo.userViewConTestQues 
WHERE (Test = 5) ORDER BY QuestionOrder} AS ParentCMD APPEND ({SELECT Answer, 
IdAnswer, Question FROM dbo.userAnswers } AS ChildCMD RELATE IdQuestion TO Question) AS ChildCMD
```

I was totally sure that the equivalence for that query would be an INNER JOIN, something like:

```
SELECT A.Test, A.IdQuestion, A.QuestionName, A.QuestionTimeLimit, A.ImageLocation,
B.Answer, B.IdAnswer FROM dbo.userViewConTestQues A INNER JOIN 
dbo.userAnswers B ON A.IdQuestion=B.Question WHERE A.Test=5 ORDER BY A.QuestionOrder
```

After debugging I got the following results:
The record count of the old program was 60, which means 60 rows, while running the new query I wrote got me more than 400 rows, so I guess I was wrong. 
What would be the 'Shape - append' equivalence nowdays?

EDIT:
60 Rows belong only to the parent recordset, however the child's recordset count is 6, but I have no idea how to get them.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly SHAPE APPEND relates parent - child data and the result is that you actually get a child recordset for each parent row. When consuming the results you have to check for that recordset and handle it appropriately (if the grid doesnt support it already).

Is it possible you are only counting the parent recordset when you say 60 rows ?

It also will give you a record from the parent recordset even if there are no rows in the child recordset so it is more like a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` but there isn't really a direct SQL equivalent that will give you the hierarchial result that the SHAPE APPEND does.

If you want to continue using the SHAPE APPEND the OleDbConnection and OleDbDataAdapter still supports that syntax but you have to add `Provider=MSDataShape` to your connection string. Then when getting the rows you would use `GetChildRows()` on the parent `DataRow` to get the child rows.

Comment: Thanks for you comment.
Running only the parent query gets me 60 rows indeed, however- in the old code they use the child recordset as well, which has 6 rows only, how would you suggest me to get these 6 rows? If I run the entire child's recordset I get hundreds of rows, there must be a condition I'm missing.

Comment: Do you mean you get six total or per parent row ?

Comment: RecordSet("ChildCMD").RecordCount equals to 6. So if I get it right, RecordSet("ParentCMD") is only the first query by itself, but I don't quite understand - what does the ChildCMD stands for then? Why is its record count 6? As you said, it has to do something with group by, but I can't get the correct query's syntax

Comment: It's difficult to answer without seeing the actual data but you should be getting the same total number of rows with the join query, it is just returned differently. While the shape had parent and childrows you are now getting all rows. It depends on what you want to use it for if that makes sense or not.